# Does the CursorLoader makes the Intents stop working?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, loader

The `Intent` inside the `onClickListener` of the `FAB` makes the app crash after implementing the `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` and its methods, but before implementing these methods the app was working just fine.
Why would the `onCreateLoader`, `onLoadFinished` and `onLoaderReset` methods make the `FAB` stops working?

Note: Not all the features of the app are currently working, i.e: Delete
I am still working on the update method.

```
//The intent in the CatalogActivity "The main activity"    
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent newIntent = new Intent(CatalogActivity.this, EditorActivity.class);
                startActivity(newIntent);
            }



//After implementing these methods the EditorActivity, the FAB in the first activity makes the app crash
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        String[] projection = {
                PetEntry._ID,
                PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME,
                PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_BREED,
                PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_GENDER,
                PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT
        };

        return new CursorLoader(this, mCurrentPetUri, projection, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {

        if (data == null || data.getCount() < 1) {
            return;
        }

        if (data.moveToNext()) {
            String name = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME));
            mNameEditText.setText(name);

            String breed = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_BREED));
            mBreedEditText.setText(breed);

            int weight = data.getInt(data.getColumnIndex(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT));
            mWeightEditText.setText(Integer.toString(weight));

            int gender = data.getInt(data.getColumnIndex(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_GENDER));

            if (gender == PetEntry.GENDER_MALE){
                mGenderSpinner.setSelection(1);
            } else if (gender == PetEntry.GENDER_FEMALE) {
                mGenderSpinner.setSelection(2);
            } else {
                mGenderSpinner.setSelection(0);
            }

        }

    }



    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        mNameEditText.setText("");
        mBreedEditText.setText("");
        mWeightEditText.setText("");
        mGenderSpinner.setSelection(0);
    }
```

Comment: Please don't just link to your code off-site. You need to include a [mcve] in the question itself, as well as the stack trace from the crash.

Comment: will edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I initialized the `loader` when the `URI` was null

```
//The old code
Intent intent = getIntent();

 mCurrentPetUri = intent.getData();

        if (mCurrentPetUri == null) {
            setTitle(getString(R.string.editor_activity_title_new_pet));

        } else {
            setTitle(getString(R.string.editor_activity_title_edit_pet));
        }
getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);
```

But I should have initialized the `loader` only the `URI` is not null

```
//The new code
Intent intent = getIntent();

        mCurrentPetUri = intent.getData();

        if (mCurrentPetUri == null) {
            setTitle(getString(R.string.editor_activity_title_new_pet));

        } else {
            setTitle(getString(R.string.editor_activity_title_edit_pet));
            getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);
        }
```